# Silverlight simple binding / dependancy property

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, dependency-properties

I've just started developing in Silverlight, and I have a calendar control which shows details for each day.

The text within the calendar is held within lots of textblocks, for some browsers the text size might be too big, so I want to have a slider control on the 'usercontrol' which allows the user to adjust the font size.

I'm building the calendar through c# code, so my question is.. what is the best way to 'wire' this up. I'm guessing it would be one of these options.

1. Add an event to the slider control for ValueChanged, then iterate through all TextBlocks setting the fontsize to the new size. This seems long-winded.
2. Maybe using a 'Style', which is attached to each TextBlock, then just changing the FontSize of the 'Style'.. ?? maybe ?
3. Using 'binding' & 'Dependancy Property'. I've looked into this, and it seems to be the way to do it, but I can't find an example where you're passing a value from one control to multiple other ones. Maybe I'm missing something.

I can do option 1 quite easily, but I want to learn about alternative methods of doing this.

Thanks
Rich.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've actually got this working now using option 3 which I'm happy with, it was very simple, but there seemed to be little documentation on it (maybe I was searching for the wrong thing).

It was as simple as adding a few lines...

```
        Binding bind = new Binding("Value");
        bind.Source = FontSlider;
```

The for every control that I want to apply the FontSlider's 'Value' to.. I do this...

```
        MyTextBlock.SetBinding(TextBlock.FontSizeProperty,bind);
```

Simples.

Cheers
Rich.

Comment: This section is for answers.  Please either leave a comment or edit your question.

Comment: I chose the option to 'Answer my own question' In that response I exaplined to the other person answering why I had answered it myself, and also outlined the answer I was looking for.

Comment: Would you prefer that I split my answer/comment into two separate posts ? I'm new to this, so don't really know how it works.

Comment: Yes, please split it up into a comment and an answer.  That way if anyone else comes along and doesn't read the *entire* post (like me) they won't flag it again.  Thanks.  :)

Answer (score 0):

A way to handle this is to not use fixed sizes but to size everything to its content. that way the control will get bigger when a larger font size is selected. Just like the TextBlock.

Comment: Yes, so a way of doing that is by allowing them to specify the font size and allow the controls to size accordingly.

Comment: The controls already size automatically to fit within the screen, and I get your point about allowing the text to automatically re-size, but the text that appears in the calendar is sometimes better viewed in a small font to see that there is something there on that day, but then expanded to show the detail. This was more of a learning thing for me, and although I realise that you can auto-adjust fonts, it wasn't applicable in this instance. Thanks for your responses anyway.

Comment: Hi Erno,

Thanks for your response, but my reason for allowing the user to re-size the text is that some screens are much smaller, but have the same resolution etc. and it's nice to allow the users to set their preferred text size.

Also, as you can probably see from above, this is all new to me, so I'm keen to learn the correct method for binding etc. so that I can use it in future projects.

PS. I originally included this comment within my 'answer', but was asked to split it. Sorry if it's confusing.

Comment: This is still way to complex. Just bind the font size of the Window or UserControl and all child controls will size along.

Comment: I'm not sure that it's 'way to complex', it's just three lines of code, and it allows me to determine which controls are effected by the font slider. Using your method, all controls on the UserControl will have their font size adjusted, and that's not what I'm aiming to do. I just want to adjust the size of the event details text which appears in the calendar. I don't want to adjust the size of the text on the buttons, or on the fontslider itself.

Comment: If possible, just group all the textblocks that you want to have their fonts sized in a control and size the control's fontsize. Individual bindings might make the the UI to hard to handle for a user and to cumbersome to maintain for a developer.